# HTTP Error 404.19 - Not Found in IIS 8.5

Tags: http-error

I have a website, which runs perfectly in `IIS 7.5`. but the same site with same configuration is not working properly in `IIS 8.5`. i am passing an system string variable in URL and it shows me

```
HTTP Error 404.19 - Not Found error.
```

So i am not able to catch the exact issue. All things are same for both IIS except IIS version only. So i need your thoughts for the problem. So that I can also look into this. Unfortunately I am new in .net, so need basic answer(s). Thanks.

If I pass `"&system=value1"`in URL for `IIS8.5` then it stops working, even this also didn't generate any log for this. So please help me for this.

**I just Came to know that if i use "sys" word in Query String then its giving error. How to avoid this issue now?**

Answer (score 6):

This can be found in IIS under Request Filtering. Usually, you will see this under the Deny String section of a rule, possibly one meant to thwart SQL Injection attacks.